# Extra character before string comparison

Tags: bash

In some bash codes, I see an extra character is added before the string comparison. Can somebody explain the reason?

```
if [ "x$VAR" = "xString" ]; then
...
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll see that to protect against the possibility of the variable being unset.  Consider, for example:

```bsh
if [ $x = "hi" ]; then echo $x; fi
```

If `x` is set to `hi`, then the behavior is:

```bsh
$ if [ $x = "hi" ]; then echo $x; fi
hi
$
```

However, if `x` is unset, then you get an error because there's nothing on the left of the `=`:

```bsh
$ if [ $x = "hi" ]; then echo $x; fi
zsh: parse error: condition expected: =
```

Adding quotes resolves the problem:

```bsh
$ if [ "$x" = "hi" ]; then echo $x; fi
$
```

Also, adding some non-blank value resolves the problem:

```bsh
$ if [ x$x = "xhi" ]; then echo $x; fi
$ x=hi
$ if [ x$x = "xhi" ]; then echo $x; fi
hi
$
```

Comment: No, that `x` prefix is not what it's about `[ x$x = "xhi" ]` is about as wrong as `[ $x = hi ]`. as the quotes are in the wrong place. `[ "$x" = hi ]` is correct with a POSIX compliant `[` but breaks with some values of `$x` such as `!` or `(` in old, broken implementations of `[`, hence the prefix.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you for the clarification.  Your answer to the linked question is very clear -- I learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably seen that without the quotes, like `[ x$VAR = xstring ]`

If for some reason VAR has not been defined, then it will not expand to anything, and the script interpreter will give an error, like `-bash: [: =: unary operator expected`. (I mean, the interpreter will see `[  = string ]` and protest against it.) By adding an extra char on both sides, you guarantee that the "nothing" will be "something", and yet the `=` will still hold.  With quotes though, you'll not get such an error, but many people just add an extra char -- out of habit, and don't pay much attention to quotes.

Comment: No, that `x` prefix is not what it's about `[ x$x = "xhi" ]` is about as wrong as `[ $x = hi ]`. as the quotes are in the wrong place. `[ "$x" = hi ]` is correct with a POSIX compliant `[` but breaks with some values of `$x` such as `!` or `(` in old broken implementations of `[`, hence the prefix.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: Yes, that too. Good point!  Although, I wouldn't say "not what it's about". (I mean, guarding against undefined variable, when there are no quotes)

Answer (score 0):

It's done to keep the string from being empty, even if `$VARIABLE` is empty. The `bash` construct

```
if [  $var = Y ]
```

misbehaves if `$var` is `""`.

Comment: The way you put it in quotes, it won't "misbehave". :-)

Comment: @porku: Thanks, fixed. My fingers have "Quote all variables" as a built-in.

Comment: No, that `x` prefix is not what it's about `[ x$x = "xhi" ]` is about as wrong as `[ $x = hi ]`. as the quotes are in the wrong place. `[ "$x" = hi ]` is correct with a POSIX compliant `[` but breaks with some values of `$x` such as `!` or `(` in old broken implementations of `[`, hence the prefix.